# Can't convert project to an executable in Python

Tags: python, windows, build, executable

I tried pyinstaller along with other stuff like psutil, and all of them work perfectly fine until you add more than one file to the question. How can I build an entire project, like a folder into an executable file?

Commands I tried:

```
pyinstaller Main.py
pyinstaller --onefile Main.py
psutil Main.py
```

None work. No errors when running the project through python with the command-line. Screen instantly closes [due to the build problems]. I started the Main.py file using the CMD and it gets the info from other files and works perfectly fine.

Spec file:

````
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['Main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Dev\\Python\\ElexEngine\\Source'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='Main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )```
````

Comment: please provide at least information like, the command you ran to build your project, the spec file, the build log, etc... no one will be able to help with so few detail

Comment: @Tryph Fair point, added additional info.